# How do I get Putty to show color coding on git output?

Tags: windows, git, colors, putty

I am using Putty on Windows 7 to connect to a VirtualBox Debian install, but I am unable to get git commands through Putty to show color coding like Git Bash does on Windows. I can get (and configure) normal Putty (ANSI?) coloring for things like files and folders, but I am not seeing anywhere how to configure colors for git command output.

Answer (score 21):

Launch:

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it doesn't highlight when tabs have been changed to spaces or vice versa like Git Bash for Windows does. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `git config color.ui true`.  If you can see colored files & folders, it means your terminal settings are correct, so Git must not be configured to display colors.